# Form with Subform - find record by updating one of two fields

Tags: database, ms-access

step by step i am advancing with my Gasoline inventory database and it is actually about to start becoming fun to try out different new things on the database.

However i got stuck on one little issue.

I have a form with a Subform.
May main form has two fields. One is the Gas Station and one is the date of the report that comes in.

Each report of any station contains one or more products with gallons sold, delivered and physical inventory (has to be applied manually as gas expands when warm)

I tried to add a macro to each of the two fields which requeries after update, but that didn't do anything.

Anyways, im looking for a solution that lets me look for past records by just updating one of the two fields in the main form.

[image]

Comment: The recordsource for your subform has the StationID in?  If so, click on the container for the subform (i.e. the box, it's sitting in not the actual subform) go to the 'Data' property sheet tab and add the StationID in the `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields`.  Your subform will now stay in sync with the main form.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a table containing the Station details - Station ID, Station Name, etc.  Something like the image below.
[image]

You'll also have a table or query that shows sales, delivery, etc for each station based on the Station ID (it'll also have a report date - forgot to add that to my example table).
[image]

When you place the subform into the main form you need to link the two forms so they stay in sync using the Master/Child fields (your StationID) which are available in the property sheet for the subform container:
[image]

Comment: hey, thank you for your effort to help me in the first place, i really appreciate that!

i checked your answer and as far as i can tell everything is linked fine. I created the form with the subform with the wizard and when i scroll through the records i can see all entries in the subform according to the Station and Date.

BUT i would like to be able to look up a certain record by updating one of those two fields on top. Right now, nothing happens, it basically just manipulates the record that is open at the moment.